# Concatenar varios csv en python

Tags: python

Cordial saludo,
Tengo una duda, requiero unir diferentes archivos .csv que no poseen encabezados. Sin embargo, al momento de unirlos se eliminan varias columnas o no se muestran.

```
files = os.path.join(path, "*.csv")
list_files = glob.glob(files)
dataframe = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, list_files), ignore_index = True, join = 'inner')
print(dataframe)
```

---

```
        17/07/2023  00:00  0  0.1  0.2
0       17/07/2023  00:10  0  0.0  0.0
1       17/07/2023  00:20  0  0.0  0.0
2       17/07/2023  00:30  0  0.0  0.0
3       17/07/2023  00:40  0  0.0  0.0
4       17/07/2023  00:50  0  0.0  0.0
```

La estructura de todos los dataframes es:

```
1       17/07/2023  00:20  0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2       17/07/2023  00:30  0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3       17/07/2023  00:40  0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4       17/07/2023  00:50  0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero verifica que los csv tengan el mismo numero de columnas, puedes hacer los siguiente:

Es mas o menos lo que tu estas haciendo pero con os

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path , "/*.csv"))

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).